# Date insertion in Cassandra DB: non-trivial 1h shift issue

Tags: php, .net, date, cassandra

I am a bit desperate about this problem... I have no idea how to face it.

Here is a simpler way to look at this problem:

If my insert cql query is:

> "BEGIN BATCH USING CONSISTENCY ONE insert into my_table(id,'2014-04-11 8:00:00',...,'2014-04-15 10:00:00') values ('2036548',3.15,...,4.11) APPLY BATCH"

...and my data request cql query is:

> "Select FIRST 100000 '2014-04-01 0:00:00'..'2014-04-16 0:00:00' from my_table where id=2036548"

...why does the inserted date *2014-04-15 **10**:00:00* changes to *2014-04-15 **11**:00:00* when pullling it from Cassandra?

The date pulling code in vb.net is:

```
Public Shared Function getCassandraDate(ByVal value As Byte()) As Date
    Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(value.Length - 1) {}
    value.CopyTo(buffer, 0)
    Array.Reverse(buffer)
    Dim ticks As Long = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 0)
    Dim dateTime As New System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, _
         0)

    dateTime = dateTime.AddMilliseconds(ticks)
    Return dateTime.ToLocalTime
End Function
```

...same thing in PHP:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Paris");
$time = $this->unpackDate($packed_time);
$str_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$time); //TODO : to local time

private function unpackDate($data, $is_name=null)
{
    $arr = unpack('N2', $data);

    // If we are on a 32bit architecture we have to explicitly deal with
    // 64-bit twos-complement arithmetic since PHP wants to treat all ints
    // as signed and any int over 2^31 - 1 as a float
    if (PHP_INT_SIZE == 4) {

        $hi = $arr[1];
        $lo = $arr[2];
        $isNeg = $hi  < 0;

        // Check for a negative
        if ($isNeg) {
            $hi = ~$hi & (int)0xffffffff;
            $lo = ~$lo & (int)0xffffffff;

            if ($lo == (int)0xffffffff) {
                $hi++;
                $lo = 0;
            } else {
                $lo++;
            }
        }

        // Force 32bit words in excess of 2G to pe positive - we deal wigh sign
        // explicitly below

        if ($hi & (int)0x80000000) {
            $hi &= (int)0x7fffffff;
            $hi += 0x80000000;
        }

        if ($lo & (int)0x80000000) {
            $lo &= (int)0x7fffffff;
            $lo += 0x80000000;
        }

        $value = $hi * 4294967296 + $lo;

        if ($isNeg)
            $value = 0 - $value;

    } else {
        // Upcast negatives in LSB bit
        if ($arr[2] & 0x80000000)
            $arr[2] = $arr[2] & 0xffffffff;

        // Check for a negative
        if ($arr[1] & 0x80000000) {
            $arr[1] = $arr[1] & 0xffffffff;
            $arr[1] = $arr[1] ^ 0xffffffff;
            $arr[2] = $arr[2] ^ 0xffffffff;
            $value = 0 - $arr[1]*4294967296 - $arr[2] - 1;
        } else {
            $value = $arr[1]*4294967296 + $arr[2];
        }
    }
    return $value / 1e3;
}
```

---

**MORE DETAILS**

**Processing chain:**

(1). insertion to Cassandra through .NET

(2). Cassandra data storage

(3). Pulling the data from PHP or .NET

**Problem:**

As for today, a date being *2014-04-15 **10**:00:00* in step (1), will come out as *2014-04-15 **11**:00:00* in step (3).

**Details:**

(regarding the date format in this chain)

(1). Local time in .NET (Timezone: "Europe/Paris"). Insertion cql that is being executed: `"BEGIN BATCH USING CONSISTENCY ONE insert into my_table(id,'2014-04-11 8:00:00',...,'2014-04-15 10:00:00') values ('2036548',3.15,...,4.11) APPLY BATCH"`

(2). *??? I don't know what Cassandra does here... ???*

(3). Example of cql query to pull the data: `"Select FIRST 100000 '2014-04-01 0:00:00'..'2014-04-16 0:00:00' from my_table where id=2036548"`. In php: `date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Paris"); $str_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$time);`. In .NET: `dateTime.ToLocalTime`.

**Extra info:**

I think it worked well before the daylight saving time change some weeks ago. But I can not be sure about that.

If in step (1), if I changed the date to de date to UTC before inserting it, *2014-04-15 **10**:00:00* will become *2014-04-15 **08**:00:00* and the output will be *2014-04-15 **09**:00:00*, which is still not correct.

I highly suspect that the trick here is between steps (1) and (2), that is to say, me not being able to understand how Cassandra treats dates.

---

**Edit1:**

@Ananth 's questions:

> both cassandra and client run in the same datacenter?

It is complicated:

- Insertion in .NET from server1, a different server from server-cassandra (datacenter).
- PHP (to pull the data) running on server-cassandra.
- .NET (to pull the data) running on server1, not on server-cassandra.
- PHP and .NET pulling the same result.

> Can you post your schema here?

Here it is

```
CREATE TABLE tsmeasures (
  id int PRIMARY KEY
) WITH
  comment='' AND
  comparator=timestamp AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=0 AND
  default_validation=double AND
  min_compaction_threshold=4 AND
  max_compaction_threshold=32 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  compaction_strategy_class='SizeTieredCompactionStrategy' AND
  compression_parameters:sstable_compression='SnappyCompressor';
```

**Edit2:**

After testing it step by step, this is the result:

- real date : 2014-04-15 17:00:00 (localtime)
- cql text : '2014-04-15 15:00:00' (to UTC, done through .NET)
- PHP Cassandra Unpack of this date => $ticks = 1397577600 (*) The unpack is done with the piece of code shown before

Ticks converted (through http://www.epochconverter.com/ )

- GMT: Tue,
- 15 Apr 2014 16:00:00 GMT Your time zone: 4/15/2014 6:00:00 PM GMT+2

These results makes no sense to me...

More details:

cql insert:

> "BEGIN BATCH USING CONSISTENCY ONE insert into tsmeasures(id,'2014-04-11 15:00:00',...,'2014-04-15 15:00:00') values ('2036548',0,...,4.85) APPLY BATCH"

cql fetch:

> "SELECT '2014-04-10 16:00:00'..'2014-04-20 17:00:00' FROM tsmeasures WHERE id IN
>   (2036548,2036479,2036174,650877)"

Thus '2014-04-15 15:00:00' is included in the range of the fetch, and I can identify it because it is the highest value.

I will keep digging...

Comment: Can you post your schema here. Not enough info the schema level. Moreover, both cassandra and client run in the same datacenter?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have added an **Edit1** to the original post providing the information you asked for. Please let me know if you need some more info.

Comment: So , you take insertion time to get the timestamp from?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood the question. I just want to clarify that my columns are timestamps, and I use these timestamps to get the corresponding values.

Comment: I have answered based on the schema you have produced. In that schema, there is not column named timestamp. Kindly check the answer and respond there if there is a misconception based on my side based on your response.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a time zone issue. It appears you are neither specifying a timezone when storing nor when retrieving the timestamps. According to the [documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html) Cassandra applies the timezone of the coordinator node handling the write request if no timezone is supplied by the client. If timestamps shift between writing and reading them, that probably means all or some of your Cassandra nodes are not configured for the same timezone as your client is.

Comment: I think we found the solution to this problem. Follow-up posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113521/date-insertion-in-cassandra-db-non-trivial-1h-shift-issue-follow-up).

Comment: This still appears to be an issue on the client side. You are fighting with fire if you are setting time zone for cassandra time stamp and operating on clients with different timezones. CPU Clocks will always vary.

Comment: @Tremor While I think there is nothing wrong with specifying a timezone for Cassandra different from the system timezone, I also agree with Ananth that it is not the solution to the problem. Rather the clients writing the timestamps should supply the timezone the timestamp originates from.

Comment: I am not using different timezones... this was the problem: 2 servers working in timezone "Europe/Zürich", input data as timezone "Europe/Zürich" (which was 100% intended), clients wanting the output data in "Europe/Zürich" timezone... BUT Cassandra running on a fix GMT+1 timezone for no reason (well, because the JVM told it so) <= this was so hard to find out..... now all the steps are aligned to the same timezone.

Comment: One could argue that it would be better to have Cassandra set as UTC, and adapt the input/output to this fact. And you would probably be right. The thing is: right now, our data flow is fixed to "localtime Europe/Zürich". And if we wanted to redesign this concept, we would now (and not before) have a clue about where we can set this "UTC" parameter in Cassandra. The fact that it was a parameter hidden in the JVM and not tuned with the server timezone was what made it so difficult.

Answer (score 0):

> Before Edit

Is there a clock time sync problem between your client and cassandra? I would strictly recommend running NTP between your client and cassandra installation.

> Post Edit

```
CREATE TABLE tsmeasures (
  id int PRIMARY KEY
) WITH
  comment='' AND
  comparator=timestamp AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=0 AND
  default_validation=double AND
  min_compaction_threshold=4 AND
  max_compaction_threshold=32 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  compaction_strategy_class='SizeTieredCompactionStrategy' AND
  compression_parameters:sstable_compression='SnappyCompressor';
```

From what you have given , it looks like you are trying to get the insertion time .

Your problem might be due to clients running in different clock cycles with respect to cassandra. Cassandra just places a unix timestamp for each write.

So what is happening here from what i see.

You write from client using timestamp X(datastax driver sets this insertion timestamp). Cassandra writes with X.

You read with a timestamp Y. Cassandra tries to read with timestamp Y(So , as per your explanation, PHP client is there in a different location).

Both a are bound to differ.

**Solution 1**

Try to have a global NTP between the entire set up so that client clock cycles are in sync with cassandra.

**Solution 2**

Insert a column named timestamp which is user driven and do a range scan based on that

**Solution 3**

Set the insertion time in DML operations.

Comment: I can also specify it in my queries:

`For example, for the date and time of Jan 2, 2003, at 04:05:00 AM, GMT:

2011-02-03 04:05:00+0000

The +0000 is the RFC 822 4-digit time zone specification for GMT. US Pacific Standard Time is -0800.`. Same thing to specify the time margins of my request. The thing is that I am still not sure what will be the timezone of the result of the request.

Comment: Now , thats application specific . In general , you gotto have the timezone of the user somewhere based on his choice and provide data to him based on that. You can autoselect the timezone based on browser request too.You have to wrap the response with appropriate timezone.

Comment: Before getting into more details, I just wanted to specify that: "PHP client is there in a different location", no, PHP runs in the same server in which Cassandra is running. But server that inserts to cassandra is not the same one. I just wanted to specify that trying to pull the data from PHP (cassandra server) or .NET (NOT cassandra server) gives the same result. All my servers are local machines, so I can check all the details... it seems that the timezones are the same in both servers.

Comment: It doesnt help either. The insert is the problem actually. If you read the answer clearly, the inserts are happening in a timezone which is having a one hour time difference .

Comment: "the inserts are happening in a timezone which is having a one hour time difference" <= it is correct. I have checked all the time zones of my two servers which are involved and they are all set to the local time of central Europe. I have added an **Edit2** with new tests, it still makes no sense to me... there is something I am missing.

Comment: Run a NTP across the two servers once and try this operation

Comment: I think we found the solution to this problem. Follow-up posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113521/date-insertion-in-cassandra-db-non-trivial-1h-shift-issue-follow-up).