# Date insertion in Cassandra DB: non-trivial 1h shift issue (follow-up)

Tags: php, date, jvm, cassandra

This is a follow-up of this [other original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080188/date-insertion-in-cassandra-db-non-trivial-1h-shift-issue/23083555?noredirect=1#comment35293404_23083555).

**ENVIRONMENT:**

Cassandra running on OpenSuse (over its Java Virtual Machine).

Server set as timezone "Europe/Zurich".

The tests include this server only. No other servers involved.

**TEST:**

```
"BEGIN BATCH USING CONSISTENCY ONE insert into tsmeasures(id,'2015-01-01 00:00:00','2015-06-01 00:00:00') values ('2812621',1,2) APPLY BATCH"
```

**RESULTS OBSERVED FROM PHP (on the same Cassandra sever):**

```
"SELECT '2014-06-01'..'2015-12-01' FROM tsmeasures WHERE id IN(2812621)"
unpacked_value=1420066800, str_time='2015-01-01 00:00:00' <= OK
unpacked_value=1433113200, str_time='2015-06-01 01:00:00' <= NOT OK !
```

Thus the dates were interpreted as GMT+1.

**SOLUTION:**

In "cassandra_env.sh", add the option -Duser.timezone when running Java:

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Duser.timezone=Europe/Zurich"
```

**REPEATING TEST AFTER THE FIX:**

```
"BEGIN BATCH USING CONSISTENCY ONE insert into tsmeasures(id,'2015-01-01 00:00:00','2015-06-01 00:00:00') values ('2812621',1,2) APPLY BATCH"
```

**NEW RESULTS OBSERVED FROM PHP AFTER THE FIX (on the same Cassandra sever):**

```
"SELECT '2014-06-01'..'2015-12-01' FROM tsmeasures WHERE id IN(2812621)"
unpacked_value=1420066800, str_time='2015-01-01 00:00:00' <= OK
unpacked_value=1433113200, str_time='2015-06-01 00:00:00' <= OK
```

Dates interpreted as:

- Central European Winter Time = GMT+1
- Central European Summer Time = GMT+2